# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast in C [error: invalid initializer]

Tags: c, data-structures

sorry for my bad english!

i have this Warning and one error in this code

> PD: this program store Watches object(ADT) in a Circular Queue

**Error and Warning**

> CQueue.c: In function ‘CQueue_Insert’:
>   CQueue.c:59:26: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>     this->queue[this->last] = x;
>
> CQueue.c: In function ‘CQueue_Remove’:
>   CQueue.c:70:14: error: invalid initializer
>     Reloj_t x = this->queue[this->first];

**CODE CIRCULAR QUEUE STRUCT**

```
typedef struct{
int* queue;
size_t first;
size_t last;
size_t max;
size_t cont;
} CQueue;
```

**Reloj_t struct**

```
typedef struct Reloj
{
  int horas;
  int minutos;
  int segundos;
 //char nombre[MAX_TAM];
 } Reloj_t;
```

**FUNCTIONS WITH PROBLEMS**

```
void CQueue_Insert( CQueue* this, const Reloj_t* x )
{
 if(CQueue_IsFull(this)==true){exit(1);}

 this->queue[this->last] = x;
 ++this->cont;
 ++this->last;
 if(this->last == this->max){
 this->last=0;
 }
}

Reloj_t CQueue_Remove( CQueue* this )//this function returns Reloj_t objects
{
 if(CQueue_IsEmpty(this) == true){exit(1);}
 Reloj_t x = this->queue[this->first];
 --this->cont;
 ++this->first;
 if(this->first == this->max){
 this->first=0;
 }
 return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the warning, you are assigning a pointer to an integer.

i.e: `this->queue[this->last]` is an integer, while `x` is a pointer(points to a Reloj_t).

I think what you're trying to do is

```
this->queue[this->last] = x->SOMESTUFF; //or something like this, depends on the definition of Reloj_t
```

I can't tell what causes the error, could you post the definition of Reloj_t?

if Reloj_t is a struct, you could do

```
Reloj_t x
x.SOMESTUFF = this->queue[this->first];
```

Comment: this->queue[this->last] = *x; //or something like this, depends on the definition of Reloj_t                                                                                                                  error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘Reloj_t {aka const struct Reloj}

Comment: use x->SOMESTUFF if reloj_t is a struct